# WordPress Litespeed Cache plugin affecting mobile display

Tags: wordpress

A particular page in the website gets breaking up in the sense the text goes out of the desired region or box (only in mobile version).

Earlier it was fine before modifications and several plugins installation but now it is having this issue. This could be because of cache issue but i don’t know for sure.

[image]

[image]

The first image is the page where I'm facing this issue the second image is in below is how I want my page to be.

You can see in the first image the word "includes" goes out of the box but in the second image it is perfect I want it to be like the second image.

**Note:** for me the issue gets resolved on uninstalling litespeed cache plugin but I want it to make website fast.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/), the free version. It has a lot of options to speed up your website without using any plugins. You can reach up to 90 scores on the gtmetrix website.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).